# Aggregating the result of calculated member in SSAS

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap-cube

Good afternoon everyone, I have some problem with the result of aggregating a calculated member in a cube. Namely: I have two groups of measures Sales and Product, where I have two measures the **sales qty** and the **product weight**, I need to calculate the qty of products sold in kg.
I created a calculated member where I multiplied these two measures.
I understand that it would be more correct to implement this immediately in the fact table, but there are some difficulties with this.
I found many examples using the SCOPE operator, but there are also problems with this, as in DSV, I use not tables, but named queries, and I can’t create a named calculation on the fact table in, can there be any other solutions to the problem?
An example picture is presented below.

Thank you in advance.

my picture link is in a comment

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8HNn.jpg

Comment: As you've correctly pointed out, this type of calculation needs to operate on the row level first before rolling up. The cube will aggregate first and then multiply, and you want to multiply first and then aggregate. Your options are limited, and I would say all of them involve operations either in the fact table, a view on top of the fact table, or in the DSV with a named calcultion. An option involving a SCOPE statement would still require some alteration in the DSV, and that option would probably still not give you the correct result.